# About tweepy's direct message request

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to automate twittter using a module called tweepy.
However, I noticed that there is no mention of direct message requests in the reference.
What should I do in this case?
Thank you.

postscript:
I am Japanese. This text was written using deepl.com, so please let me know if there are any strange parts.